# Convert 32bit binary string to byte

Tags: java, string, casting, binary, byte

I am using FileInputStream to read a single byte at a time, I then turn it into a string using the Integer.toBinaryString(), and later  need to cast it back into a byte.

here's my problem: java uses a 32bit byte, meaning that my string returned by Integer.toBinaryString() has a length of 32, and I've been getting quite frustrated trying to convert that back into a byte because methods like Byte.valueOf() and so on, all throw an error pertaining to the value being out of byte range.

Am I missing something? Or do I need to develop my own method.

Comment: I mean you can just 0xff & your number... but I feel that your workflow could be easier.

Comment: I won't lie, I'm clueless about the 0xff thing. But I will say that I need precision. I'm aware that I can convert the 32bit binary back into a byte using some arithmetic, I had just hoped that there would be a library that tackles this issue. I mean why make the byte 32bits when the rest of the libraries won't deal with it, so to say.lol. And I'm not that knowledgeable in bit and byte arithmetic.

Comment: For example, 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 equals -1 , and I currently don't know java's byte 'protocol' enough to deal with that, so I had hoped for a quick library method.

Comment: According to [the Java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1), byte type is 8-bits length and is able to hold values from -128 to 127 (inclusive). So you cannot store 32-bits value in 8-bits byte type. You need to use at least `int` or `long` type.

Comment: `byteValue & 0xff` is the correct thing to do;  it preserves the lowest eight bits of an int and sets all other bits to zero, since a bitwise “and” with 0 clears a bit and a bitwise “and” with 1 preserves it, and ff₁₆ = 11111111₂.  Since a byte only has eight meaningful bits anyway, no precision is lost.  InputStream returns bytes as int values because all numeric operators operate on ints and longs only, and because in a 32-bit architecture, any operation on an 8-bit or 16-bit number is likely to have the same cost as operating on a 32-bit number.

Comment: Thanks everyone. 0xff now makes more sense to me. I think I'll do just that, truncate the rest and deal with the relevant 8 bits, then later I'll add the rest of the 26 bits back, which all seem to be 1's. Also, it seems that the 32 bits issue only arises when the bytes value is negative.

Comment: If you tell us about what you are trying to do with the string and number.  We might be able to give you a better solution.  I mean if you already have it as a byte why do you convert it to an int then back to byte again?

Comment: I convert it into a string to 'observe' each bit, this is necessary, and the value of the entire byte is not that important so to say. So it's necessary that I deal with each bit. But because I'm working with a file, I need to put everything back into its proper format when I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the simple answer :|

```
public class abc
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        byte b = -1;
        String binString = Integer.toBinaryString(b); //value 1111,1111,1111,1111,1111,1111,1111,1111
        new BigInteger(binString, 2).byteValue(); //value -1 
    }
}
```

It truncates the binString, but that doesn't effect the byte value, because the 24 bits on the left aren't really relevant to the byte.

Now, in the example above I'm using a BigInteger and its byteValue() method, the reason for that, and why I'm not just using a 0xff solution, is because the Integer.toBinaryString() in the code above will return a string digit (32 1's) with a length of 32 and this cannot be casted into an int or even a long, because it is too large a number/value. As a result of that, not being able to cast it into an int or long, one can't perform operations like & on it, so the solution is to trim the string of the of the 24 bits on the left, then one can cast/convert the shorter string into an int, which is what BigInteger does in the code above.

The byte will still maintain its value, because the value is only contained in the 8 bits on the right(staying true to what a byte is). The added 24 bits that java sometimes adds to the 8 bit byte, is for java's own purposes and can be ignored if need be, such as the example, the problem which spawned this thread.